# Remove checkmark from LWC lightning-input toggle

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput

Is there a way to remove the checkmark when the toggle is in the checked state?
[image]

This is what I have on my HTML -

```
<lightning-input type="toggle" name="test" data-id={testId} data-name={testName} message-toggle-active="Active" message-toggle-inactive="Inactive" onchange={handleToggleChange}></lightning-input></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CSS to remove the checkmark from the toggle when the checked state. Use the `border-style` CSS attribute set to `none`. Add the below CSS code into your component CSS file.

```
.slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux_container .slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux_container .slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux_container .slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux_container .slds-checkbox--faux:after {
        border-style: none !important;
}
```

---

Updated Code::

HTML::

```
<template>
<label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
<span class="slds-form-element__label cxd-toggle__label-medium">Block List</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="cxdBlockCB" onchange={unlockCheckboxesRelaxed} checked={relaxedChecked} disabled={relaxedDisabled} />
<span class="slds-checkbox_faux_container" style="float: left;">
        <span class="slds-checkbox_faux" style="float: left;"></span>
        <span class="slds-checkbox_on" style="float: right; margin: 6px;">Active</span>
        <span class="slds-checkbox_off" style="float: right; margin: 6px;">Inactive</span>
</span>
<span class="slds-form-element__label slds-assistive-text">Toggle</span>
</label>
</template>
```

JS::

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
export default class ToggleCheckboxLWC extends LightningElement {
}
```

CSS::

```
.slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux_container .slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux_container .slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked~.slds-checkbox--faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux_container .slds-checkbox_faux:after, .slds-checkbox--toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox--faux_container .slds-checkbox--faux:after {
    border-style: none !important;
}
```

Output::

[image]

Comment: Hello Tushar, Thanks for the response.  But it is not working for me. Also I am not understanding the CSS as well.

Comment: @sumchans I have updated and added code with output in my answer please check.